# How to convert uint16_t[2N] to uint32_t[N] effectively?

Tags: c, arrays, embedded

I've got an array of six `uint16_t` which is actually three `uint32_t`, with the bits in the right order and all. How can I cast the former to the latter as effectively as possible?

The number of elements in the array is known at compile-time.

Comment: For such a small amount, just loop over the source array, and put the result in the destination array. Just remember to increase the index by two.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How does the array size matter? The conversion is going to happen a lot of times, so efficiency is important.

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency then you should *measure* it first. It might not be the big bottleneck you think it is.

Comment: @JimBalter The program is for Atmega328, which is little-endian. The first uint16 contains the high bits. That's all I need to know, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this perhaps:

```
uint16_t arr16[6];
uint32_t *parr32 = (uint32_t*)(&arr16);
```

And now you can use `parr32[i]` to refer to elements of the overlayed `arr16` array.

Comment: Note that this answer assumes that when you stated "with the bits in the right order and all", that statement was correct. Obviously, if that statement that you made was not correct, then the question changes entirely. And if that statement was not correct, then you cannot cast one array to the other.

Comment: Beware of alignment issues.  Some processors may require the uint32_t to be aligned on a 32-bit boundary.  But since arr16 is declared as a uint16_t it may not be aligned on a 32-bit boundary.  Then casting arr16 to a uint32_t may produce undefined behavior. You may be able to use a compiler specific pragma directive to force arr16 to be aligned on a 32-bit boundary.